# synonym token filter not working the same in elasticsearch v2.4 vs v1.6

Tags: elasticsearch

v2.4 brings back many more (unwanted) results than v1.6. Mapping is the same between the two. Settings (analyzers, tokenizers, etc) are the same between the two. The analyzer is very complex with tokenizing and synonyms.

The query analysis is:

```
GET /partsearch/epicorpart/_validate/query?explain
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "partDescription" : {
                "query":      "qp-09-04",
                "operator":   "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The analysis result for v2.4:

```
"+(partDescription:qp-09-04 partDescription:qp partDescription:quality-plan partDescription:09 partDescription:04 partDescription:qp partDescription:quality-plan partDescription:-09-04 partDescription:09 partDescription:04) #ConstantScore(+ConstantScore(_type:epicorpart))"
```

The analysis result for v1.6:

```
"filtered(+partDescription:qp-09-04 +(partDescription:qp partDescription:quality-plan partDescription:09 partDescription:04) +(partDescription:qp partDescription:quality-plan partDescription:-09-04 partDescription:09 partDescription:04))->cache(_type:epicorpart)"
```

**UPDATE:**
Found a difference between my indexes in v1.6 and v2.4. When comparing output of _analyze?analyzer=descriptionanalyzer&text=QP-01 the output is different as seen in the gist linked below. The same analyzer is used for both. In v2.4 all of the tokens have position number 0 whereas in V1.6 the tokens have various position numbers. Also some of the types differ with 2.4 having "word" and 1.6 having "synonym". Looks like the position numbers are how the tokens are grouped in the explain results shown above.

**UPDATE 2:**
Narrowed problem down a bit further. The difference I'm seeing between the two versions seems to come down to the synonym token filter. In version 1.6 once the synonym token filter does its thing the token position numbers are changed. The token position numbers do not get changed by the synonym token filter in version 2.4.

**Gist** with settings, mapping, and _analyze output: https://gist.github.com/cooperhj/409f25f8d3274847a1a117fa47a9e0de

Suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like it would help to have a test case. If you can produce a new index, some test data and results you get for both 1.6 and 2.4 it would help. Share them in a gist.

Comment: Why down voted? At least leave a comment or question

Comment: @AndreiStefan Updated my issue after more investigation and I've added a link to a gist with additional info. Would greatly appreciate it if you could look it over.

Comment: I'll look at it on Monday.

Comment: You provided an almost complete set of test data. The part missing the is the synonym token filter file.

Comment: Synonym token filter file added to gist. Thanks so much for your time